# Why do we need Java Plugin to download videos from YouTube, Vimeo etc

Tags: java, video, plugins, youtube, download

There are websites like http://keepvid.com/ which let us download videos but they required us to install Java plugin, whereas there are websites like http://dirpy.com/ which does the same but without any Java plugin.

What is the difference here? What exactly is the Java plugin doing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This is blatanty off topic for this website, just saying.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really a programming question. I thought it was worth an answer, though, if only to explain why Java applets are a terrible idea and are barely used anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java used to be quite popular as a web technology in applet form (these days, Java is more commonly used on the backend). Eventually, it was decided that Java applets were both slow and insecure, and they were largely abandoned in favor of more recent standards such as HTML5 and JavaScript. http://keepvid.com/ probably uses a Java applet to download a youtube video using the user's internet connection, something that is disallowed under the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) by JavaScript, for very good reason (it is highly insecure and opens up many avenues for attack).

My guess would be that http://keepvid.com/ was created back when Java applets were still used. Newer sites use different technologies to do the job.